# CRA - Upgrading react-scripts to 5.0.1 breaks storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, migrate

In my CRA, I am using storybook version 6.4.22, I was using react-scripts v 4.0.3 and have changed to version 5.0.1 however this has broken the storybook.

As per the instructions I did `npx sb@next automigrate` but now I get the error:

```
ERR! ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
ERR!  - configuration.module.rules[4] should be one of these:
ERR!    ["..." | object { assert?, compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, scheme?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
```

This is just some of the errors.

I know react-scripts uses version 5 of webpack, so must be something to do with that?

Comment: This already has been discussed on [Storybook github issues](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues?q=react-scripts++Invalid+configuration+object) page, have you tried looking there?

Comment: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17357

Comment: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15028

Comment: [Issues with starting Storybook after upgrading to CRA 5](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/17454)

Comment: Add as an answer, so I can accept ti, thanks

Comment: Happy to have helped, but me answering such a question would be earning points in an unethical way for me because I believe such questions shouldn't have been asked before first search the Github repo's issues, and also it should have been reported there and not here, where Storybook maintainers cannot possibly do anything. This is a Storybook issue which should be filed there.

Comment: Belongs to Storybook github issues page